# Choosing a random number between a and b

Tags: python

I want to write a program that receives two words, `Min` and `Max`, and chooses a random number between them. How should I do this?

```
import random 
a = input('min :')
b = input('max : ')
c = random.randint(a,b)
print(c)
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code?

Comment: You got homework?

Comment: Why was this closed with needing debugging details? The issue is very clear.

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal Because the user is supposed to indicate what error they are actually getting in the question. (If nothing else, forcing the user to do so may make them notice the obvious error, negating the need to post the question in the first place.)

Answer (score 1):

The issue here lies with the datatypes. When you take an input using the `input()` function, it returns a string, even if you type a number. So if I type 5 and 10 it has `a == "5"` and `b == "10"`, and a random number between `"5"` and `"10"` is the same as saying a random number between `"apple"` and `"banana"`. To fix this, convert it to an integer like so:

```py
import random

a = int(input('min :'))
b = int(input('max : '))
c = random.randint(a,b)
print(c)
```

Comment: I didn't downvote but I guess that someone thought that such a poorly written question doesn't deserve an answer.

Comment: Perhaps... Doesn't matter too much anyway, I would just like to know...